# How to match a single Unicode character in single quotes

Tags: javascript, unicode, grammar, peg, pegjs

My language has single-quoted Unicode character literals like:

```js
'h'
''
```

etc.

I'm using the following rule to parse this:

```
CHAR = "'" (!"'" c:.) "'" { return c; }
```

This works for ASCII characters, but unfortunately not for Unicode.

How can I modify this to match a single Unicode character like the emoji above?

Comment: When you say "Unicode", are you talking about UTF-16 surrogate pairs specifically? Or does it fail for anything out of the base code page?

Comment: [This Github issue is probably very much of interest.](https://github.com/pegjs/pegjs/issues/586)

Comment: Bottom line is that PegJS (original version) did not support surrogate pairs, basically at all. There appear to be a couple of forks of the original project out there that may have better support.

Comment: AFAIK [peggy](https://github.com/peggyjs/peggy) is the official successor.
I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by parsing character literals as strings.

Then, in JS, I spread the string into individual unicode codepoints.

If there are more than 1 codepoints, I throw a parse error.

Otherwise, I pick the first codepoint.

Answer (score -1):

That seems to work:

```
CHAR = "'" c:$([\u0800-\uffff]?.) "'" { return c; }
```